# drag to create jQuery UI draggable and move with mouse until released

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mouseevent, draggable

After I drag some `html` element I need it to duplicate itself, change some things, become jQuery UI draggable and move along with mouse cursor **until** I release the mouse.

So far I managed to clone, alter and do draggable (see http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/qdVue) I can't make it to move with cursor no matter what I do.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is set a global variable to be the current object and monitor the `MouseMove` event of the element (or document) and set the left/top position of the element to be that of the mouse.

```
var currentObj = null;

$(".js-factory")
    .on("mousedown", ".js-form .js-base", function (event) {
        var figurka = $(this).clone(false).addClass("figurka").draggable({
            snapMode:   "inner",
            snapTolerance   :   55
        }).wrapInner("<div class='fig-wrap'></div>");
        $(".js-park").append(figurka);
        currentObj = figurka;
    });
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (currentObj) {
        currentObj.css({'top':e.clientY - 20, 'left':e.clientX - 20});
    }
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    currentObj = null;
});
```

In the previous code we set the value of `currentObj` to be that of the `figurka` object ou create, we then monitor the `mousemove` event of the document and the created object is moved to the position of the mouse -20. Once the `mouseup` event occurs on the document we reset the `currentObj` to be `null`.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y8Ua/1/)

**EDIT**

There seems to be an odd occurrence in my Fiddle as to why the position of the element is not at the mouse. This is being caused by the `float:right;` CSS property for your `base` element.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I tweaked it a bit and made use of jQuery UIs' .position({of: e}) so it's working without any hassle even with float:right. I also added hiding so there is no visible repositioning of new element. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/qdVue/1/